# Is $\{ w \in L : wx \in L, \textrm{for some } x \neq \epsilon\}$ a CFG language if $L$ is CFG?

Tags: context-free, closure-properties

Let $L$ be CFG. Is $\{ w \in L : wx \in L, \textrm{for some } x \neq \epsilon\}$ also CFG?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual questions but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you. Also, your question is answered by standard [closure properties of context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Closure).

Comment: The question asks for the *intersection* of the proper prefix language of $L$ with $L$. Context-free languages are not closed under intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the language
$$
L = \{ a^n b^m c^nd : n,m \geq 0 \} \cup \{ a^n b^m c^m d^2 : n,m \geq 0 \}.
$$
Then $\{ w \in L : wx \in L \text{ for some } x \neq \epsilon \} \cap a^* b^* c^* d = \{ a^n b^n c^n d : n \geq 0 \}$.

Here is a similar example, showing that if $L$ is context-free then $L \cap L \Sigma^+$ is not necessarily context-free:
$$
L = \{ a^n b^n : n \geq 0 \} \cup \{ a^n b^m c^m : n,m \geq 0 \}.
$$
Indeed, in this case $L \cap L\Sigma^+ = \{ a^n b^n c^n : n \geq 0 \}$.

The situation is likely different for *deterministic* context-free languages.